# C++ multiple template pure virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, linker

I have managed to get rid of ambiguity error when using overloaded functions from multiple parents by using template with parent resolution, but this gives linker error when looking for AddObjectImpl, which is strange since that function is virtual.

```
template<typename T>
class ObjectHandler
{
public:
    virtual void AddObjectImpl(T& obj) = 0;
    virtual void ClearObjectImpl(T& obj) = 0;
};

class INTERFACE_API IModel
    : public ObjectHandler<type1>,
    public ObjectHandler<type2>
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void AddObject(T& obj)
    {
        this->ObjectHandler<T>::AddObjectImpl(obj);
    }
    template<typename T>
    void ClearObject(T& obj)
    {
        this->ObjectHandler<T>::ClearObjectImpl(obj);
    }
};
// In different project
class CModel : public IModel
{
    virtual void AddObjectImpl(type1& o) override;
    virtual void AddObjectImpl(type2& o) override;
    virtual void ClearObjectImpl(type1& o) override;
    virtual void ClearObjectImpl(type2& o) override;
}
// And then the implementation ...
```

EDIT1: The error happens at call to AddObject :

```
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
 "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void __cdecl
 ObjectHandler<class type1>::AddObjectImpl(class type1 &)"
 (/*removed*/) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl
 IModel::AddObject<class type1>(class type1 &)"
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: `this->ObjectHandler<T>::AddObjectImpl(obj);` is not a virtual call. you should try `((ObjectHandler<T>*) this)->AddObjectImpl(obj)`.

Comment: @Franck That seems to be working, though I don't understand why it wasn't virtual call, and why your answer works. If you could add your answer so I can select it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `this->ObjectHandler<T>::AddObjectImpl(obj);` is not a virtual/dynamic call but a static call since you qualify your call.

You should replace it by `((ObjectHandler<T>*) this)->AddObjectImpl(obj)` to call the right virtual method.

In a code like

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual void f();
};
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    virtual void f();
};

Base* base = new Derived;
```

The call

```
base->Base::f();
```

statically calls the base method `Base::f` whereas `((Base*) base)->f()` dynamically calls `Derived::f` by searching it in the virtual method table. This is the same case with your code.

Note that with

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
};
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    virtual void f() {}
};

Base* base = new Derived;
base->Base::f();
```

The compiler compiles it even if it could deduce that it is a static call to a pure virtual method. At the end, the linker complains with the error message `undefined reference to Base::f()`